# Interacting With Contract Web3.js

Tags: javascript, blockchain, smartcontracts, web3js, avalanche

I have been trying to interact with a contract on the AVAX chain using web3js and it keeps throwing the error, "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')". I cannot figure out why this is happening, as it should be a valid statement. If anyone can help that would be awesome.

```
  const contract = new Contract(*abi*, '0x82194f7d4Ded53A546ec4e3A7a57f81C5a54E194');
  console.log("transaction sent");
  await contract.methods.transfer(address, amount).send({to: "0xxxxxx"});
  console.log("transaction sent really");
}
```

Also, is it acceptable to paste the abi directly into the constructor in between [] brackets, like so? `const contract = new Contract(*abi*, '0x82194f7d4Ded53A546ec4e3A7a57f81C5a54E194');`

Here is the Contract ABI

```
    "status": "1",
    "message": "OK",
    "result": "[{\"inputs\":[],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"constructor\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"owner\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"spender\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":false,\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"value\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"Approval\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"previousOwner\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"newOwner\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"OwnershipTransferred\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"from\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"to\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":false,\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"value\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"Transfer\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"owner\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"spender\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"allowance\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"spender\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"amount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"approve\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"bool\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"account\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"balanceOf\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"amount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"burn\",\"outputs\":[],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"account\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"amount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"burnFrom\",\"outputs\":[],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"decimals\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint8\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint8\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"spender\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"subtractedValue\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"decreaseAllowance\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"bool\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"spender\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"addedValue\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"increaseAllowance\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"bool\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"to\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"amount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"mint\",\"outputs\":[],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"name\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"string\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"owner\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"renounceOwnership\",\"outputs\":[],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"symbol\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"string\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"totalSupply\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"to\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"amount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"transfer\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"bool\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"from\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"to\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"amount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"transferFrom\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"bool\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"newOwner\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"transferOwnership\",\"outputs\":[],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"}]"
  }]
```

Comment: It seems like the ABI doesn't contain definition of the `transfer()` function or is malformed... It should be an array of objects, each of these objects describing a function or an event. They should not be wrapped in another `abi` property, etc.. Can you check that or post the whole thing?

Comment: Just posted the ABI, It appears to contain the transfer method, would the issue in the send functionality be caused by the abi, or could it be something else? Thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ABI needs to contain just the function and event definitions that are stored in your `result` property. Without the wrapper object containing `status` and other properties.

So in your case

```
const abi = [{"inputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"burn","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"burnFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"","type":"uint8"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"subtractedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"decreaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"addedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"increaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}];
```

Comment: Ok, this worked great, I get another error when I attempt to send the transaction and that is 
```Error: Provider does not have a request or send method to use.```
If you know how to fix this, it would be super appreciated, thanks so much again. 
Im using Metamask as a provider